# Equivalent of blobstore.create_upload_url in GCS?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

We use blobstore.create_upload_url in our application and I like that way this it works for uploading files clientside.
If we are to start using Google Cloud Storage (GCS) instead, what is the equivalent of create_upload_url() in GCS?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to answer the question:[Google App Engine - Using Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592661/google-app-engine-using-blobstore-api-with-google-cloud-storage?rq=1)

> When the user submits an upload web form, the uploaded data goes
>   directly to the Blobstore or to Google Cloud Storage if you use that
>   instead of Blobstore. (Google Cloud Storage requires the
>   gs_bucket_name parameter.) The Blobstore rewrites the incoming request
>   to remove the uploaded data (the MIME part body) and add the Blobstore
>   key (as a header in the MIME part), then passes the rewritten request
>   to the application handler associated with the URL path given to
>   create_upload_url() as success_path. The handler at that path can
>   process the rest of the form.